# Getting "How do you want to run this type of file (.html)" when trying to install AVG antivirus

Tags: windows-8

I am trying to install AVG antivirus on my fresh Windows 8.1 Pro installation. When trying to run autorun.exe, it keeps asking me "How do you want to run this type of file (.html)" and shows me options as Chrome, IE etc.

I have done some reading where various posts suggesting modifying registry to get this done.

Is this the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: `autorun.exe` sounds like a CD/DVD. Can you either clarify where you are getting this file from or simply try downloading a fresh copy **from the manufacturer of the software**. Those shiny plastic discs are "outdated" right after they have cooled down coming off the press, especially for antivirus software and drivers you might want to avoid that. ;-) Also especially in IT something rarely is "the only way" to accomplish something.

Comment: Thanks I went ahead and opened it with html and it actually is a web based interface for installation. Different than what it is usually.

Thanks much for all the help.

Comment: Maybe if you didn't install any additional browsers, Internet Explorer would simply have been used without any prompts at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you downloaded, then you did not download the installation file. Instead, you downloaded a HTML file (a web page), probably as you right-clicked some download link and selected "Save as", while that download link did not really refer to the installation file directly. Just left-click the download link and wait for the download to start, or follow any instructions you get there.

If this is some installation cd instead, then just select one of the options to have the file opened by the browser of your choice, and follow the instructions you get then.

Comment: Its a CD shipped by the manufacturer.

Comment: Okay, then just pick a browser when asked to.

Comment: It might have asked the question because of the "strange" origin for an .html file. Not entirely sure though.